# What do you call the parameter of a crossfader?

Tags: terminology

A crossfade or crossfader or crossfading control is a control (physical or virtual) that allows someone to smoothly vary an output from one extreme to another. For example, a disc jockey might use a crossfader to smoothly switch audio output from one record to another, usually two records that have been beat-matched.

There is a parameter here; the proportion of the right-hand signal in use. What is the name of this parameter? It can be used to complete these sentences:

- When the ____ is 0, only the left-hand signal is audible.
- When the ____ is 1, only the right-hand signal is audible.
- When the ____ is 0.5, the left-hand and right-hand signals are equally audible.

So far I have thought of "bias".

Comment: What's wrong with "crossfade" or "crossfader"? Either would seem to fit your sentences.

Comment: @Stuart, I want to avoid overloading the term "crossfade", so I don't want to use the same word to refer to the control and its parameter.

Comment: The disc jockey example is only an example. I don't want a word that presupposes that the application of the crossfader is to audio output; it has to fit for visual or other output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ratio.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ratio):
> ratio - the relationship in quantity, amount, or
> size between two or more things : proportion.

Comment: The acceptance of this answer made me think a bit more. I have revised my own accordingly. Ratio is neither justified nor conventional in these particular circumstances.

Comment: Does it really sound so weird? If somebody was explaining the crossfader, couldn't they say: "This is the crossfader. It sets the ratio of the outputs of these two decks in the master output. When it's zero, you only hear the left deck,..." ?

Comment: eltomito. You are correct that to say that when the (right:left) ratio is zero (0:1) you only hear the left. But if you say that the ratio is one, that means 50-50 left-right (0.5:0.5). Only if you say the ratio is infinite (1:0) will the output be completely on the right. And the question is about controls that go from 0 to 1, not 0 to infinity. So it is not appropriate to speak of a ratio.

Comment: @G.Rem Merriam Webster has the usual use of ratio:. the indicated quotient of two mathematical expressions; the relationship in quantity, amount, or size between two or more things : proportion. From that viewpoint and conventional use, ratio is a number.

Comment: @Anton I think that the term ratio is actually used when applying effects in audio processing and it always goes from 0 to 1, because it's the ratio between the wet sound (i.e., the sound with the effect applied) to the total output volume. Similarly here, the ratio would be that of the right deck to the total volume, i.e. right / ( right + left ). That way, it goes from 0 to 1 which feels natural. Balance, on the other hand, usually goes from -1 to 1 with 0 being the middle setting when both left and right speakers are set to the same volume. -1 is left only, 1 is right only.

Answer (score 2):

Possible usages are *setting* or *balance*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/setting)
> *setting*:
> the manner, position, or direction in which something is set

Alternatively, in most music systems this is called the "balance".

See for example:

> [Essence](https://www.essenceelectrostatic.com/use-the-balance-control-to-move-your-sweet-spot/)
> *balance*:
> Since the beginning of the stereo era, a balance control has been a standard feature included in all integrated amps, pre-amps, and receivers. Why? Because rooms are not always symmetrical and the furniture placement dictates the position of the speaker system in many homes, it is not always possible to arrange for the listening position to be centered exactly between the two main channels. The purpose of the balance control is to equalize the output levels at your listening position even when its not centered between the two main channels.

Both *setting* and *balance* relate to the *ratio* of left and right. However, this ratio will vary between zero (0:1 = 0) and infinity (1:0 = infinity), so the term *ratio* does not relate to your usage, which demands a value of 0 to 1.

We often speak of the setting of the balance control. but not of the balance of the setting.

Of the three I therefore suggest that *balance* is the most appropriate to your circumstances.